# how to remove duplicate words from a line of a file using perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and looking for a perl solution for a relatively simple problem. I want to remove duplicate words from a line of a file using perl. All the examples on web deal with duplicate lines, but I am looking for removing duplicate words. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my file

```
lot=list("XI_PBIAS.mMN_VDD_CAP1_BM" "XIBIAS2.mNCS_BIAS_BM" "XIBIAS2.mNCS_BIAS_BM"          "XIBIAS1.mNCS_PCAS_BIAS_BM" "XIBIAS1.mNCS_PCAS_BIAS_BM" "XI_PBIAS.mNCS_PCS_BIAS_BM" )
filename  = "tx_dac_bias_tb"
openResults(strcat(filename ".raw"))
```

I want the strings `"XIBIAS2.mNCS_BIAS_BM"` and `"XIBIAS1.mNCS_PCAS_BIAS_BM"` to appear only once. How do I reads the file word by word instead of line by line.

Comment: You should give a code example of what you have tried so far, to get specific help.

Comment: Is this your actual input, or some kind of code?

Comment: "All the examples on web deal with duplicate lines" Seems a bit of a reach. Even the _first_ Google result for `remove duplicate words perl` looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

Read the file line by line, then split it into words.

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @words = split;
   ...
}
```

How to remove duplicates is answered in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html).

```
my %seen;
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @words;
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
 
open(FH,"tx_dac_bias_tb.awd");

my @array;

my %seen = <FH>;

my @unique = grep { $seen{$_}++ } @array;

print FH @array;

close FH;

This code doesnt seem to help. Can you please elaborate on your solution.

Comment: @sagar : I updated the solution as you posted this comment. Give it a try now.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
 
open(FH,"tx_dac_bias_tb.awd");

my @array;

my %seen = <FH>;

my @unique = grep { $seen{$_}++ } @array;

print FH @array;

close FH;

This code doesnt seem to help. Can you please elaborate on your solution.

Comment: @sagar : 1. And you need to print `@unique`. 2. The way you've written your code, you cannot print to the same filehandle as the one you are reading from.

Comment: Don't put the words in `%seen`, put them in `@words`.

Answer (score 2):

This shows how you can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords) (core module in perl 5) to parse your quoted string inside parentheses. Note that this does not preserve the original whitespace. You will also have to specify which kind of line to match, as it seems not all lines in your input are supposed to be deduped.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^(.+=\s*list\()(.*)(\).*)$/) {
        my ($pre, $line, $post) = ($1, $2, $3);    # split into fields
        my @list = quotewords('\s+', 1, $line);    # find quoted strings
        @list = uniq(grep defined, @list);         # dedupe, remove empty
        $_ = "$pre@list$post";                     # join the line back up
    }
    print "$_\n";
}

__DATA__
lot=list("XI_PBIAS.mMN_VDD_CAP1_BM" "XIBIAS2.mNCS_BIAS_BM" "XIBIAS2.mNCS_BIAS_BM"          "XIBIAS1.mNCS_PCAS_BIAS_BM" "XIBIAS1.mNCS_PCAS_BIAS_BM" "XI_PBIAS.mNCS_PCS_BIAS_BM" )
filename  = "tx_dac_bias_tb"
openResults(strcat(filename ".raw"))
```

To use on an input file, replace `<DATA>` with `<>` and use like this:

```
perl script.pl input.txt
```

Comment: I am getting compilation error for package,Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /net/cmp1/disk1/aura/design_bin/perlpackage /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) I am working on a client machine so cannot install the required packages. Is there any work around?

Comment: @sagar You can either install the package, or just use the code for uniq itself, it is rather simple. It is the same code ikegami has used in his post `my %seen; my @unique = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @list`

Comment: @sagar Nevermind, I just added the code. Not much sense loading the whole module for 4 lines of code.

Comment: "my" variable %seen masks earlier declaration in same scope at bias1.pl line 13.
syntax error at bias1.pl line 11, near ")

sub uniq "
Can't use global $_ in "my" at bias1.pl line 13, near "{$_"
syntax error at bias1.pl line 14, near "}"
Execution of bias1.pl aborted due to compilation errors. I get the above error when the code is run. Can you please point to the mistake in the pointer. Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: "my" variable %seen masks earlier declaration in same scope at bias1.pl line 13.
syntax error at bias1.pl line 11, near ")

sub uniq "
Can't use global $_ in "my" at bias1.pl line 13, near "{$_"
syntax error at bias1.pl line 14, near "}"
Execution of bias1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @sagar You're welcome. If you feel your question is answered, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl regex
s/(.*)\1/$1/g